# How can we add minification in yii2 frontend application?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to add minfication for css and js files or can i add minify them and add in single file .I have added some css and js file for full application and others are page wise?

Answer (score 0):

**AssetBundle** represents a collection of asset files, such as CSS, JS, etc.

An asset bundle can depend on other asset bundles. When registering an asset bundle with a view, all its dependent asset bundles will be automatically registered.

**please refer below link**

[Yii2 AssetBundle API DOC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html)

[AssetBundle Example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-working-with-asset-bundles--cms-23226)

In Your **Yii2 Basic Application**

[Yii2 Basic Application Asset Bundle Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821048/css-and-bootstrap-in-yii2/37826716#37826716)

In Your **Yii2 Advanced Application**

First create one `AppAsset` AssetBundule in your **frontend->assets->AppAsset.php**.

```
<?php

    namespace frontend\assets;
    use yii\web\AssetBundle;

    class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
    {
        public $basePath = '@webroot';
        public $baseUrl = '@web';
        public $css = [
             ....
             css file here
             ....
        ];
        public $js = [      
             .... 
             js file here
             .... 
        ];
        public $jsOptions = [
             ....
             js options here
             ....
        ];
        public $depends = [
             ....
             dependent asset bundles here
             eg: 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'
             ....
        ];
    }
?>
```

Now register the `AppAsset` in your **view** file

```
<?php
   use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
   AppAsset::register($this);
?>
```

And Also Register Single js and css file

[Single Js ans Css File Register](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html)

Comment: @vishnu yes added css and js to appasset but it will load files seperatly, i want to minify files to less the load time.

Comment: @Techie this method is best to load js and css file using assets bundle in yii2 application

Comment: you are right, but this method loads all files separate.Means if i have five js file it will load five files separetly and increase load time, how to minify them before load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/skeeks-semenov/yii2-assets-auto-compress

It is easy and fast to configure. Once installed you only need to update your config file.

i.e

```
'components' => [
        'assetsAutoCompress' => [
            'class' => '\skeeks\yii2\assetsAuto\AssetsAutoCompressComponent',
        ],
```

and then bootstrap it.

```
'bootstrap' => ['log', 'assetsAutoCompress'],
```

That's it then you are ready to go.